# Android GTalk, Chromium Gtalk, Gmail Gtalk - how can i send files such as image, music, video clips like whatsApp?

Tags: file-transfer, google-talk, whatsapp-messenger, chat

I am using on my Android Gtalk where i can only do chat text send and receive. But how can i do all the features of WhatsAPP from Gtalk?

Features like:

- file transfer (image pictures, music, video clips)
- Audio replay from the chat by history
- Video reply from the chat by history

Is there any way to make Gtalk by default to do file transfer features?? So that pictures in mobile can be sent, musics in mobile can be sent etc can be sent from mobile directly ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rumored Google Babel](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+babel&aq=f&oq=google+babel&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60j0l2j62.1726j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) may be the solution you are looking for. Hopefully it will be announced/released before or at Google I/O.

Comment: That would be a great because Google Babel to have. All Google products are the cool. WhatsAPP is very evil mind, its not allow Unix/Linux users to run friendly from desktop there apps, we have to always use emulator for there craps. But having Google on this will help us to relax by sitting our old OS and use the same simple crap what whatsAPP was trying to make complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Google Talk doesn't have any of those features. It's meant as a complement to Gmail, and it's intended that if you want to send files or persistent things to your chat partner, you'd email them.

If you want a chat system that has all the features of WhatsApp, why not just use WhatsApp?

Comment: WhatsAPP is only for mobile with 3G, Wifi. But i use Unix or Linux or sometimes my Android only. And everything i do with Google. Just for file transfer feature i have to day and night use whatsAPP which is abnormal choice. So i do not use whatsAPP, but looking forward to have file transfer feature in Gtalk, which makes the life easier.

Comment: Gtalk is open source, why not a single person willing to add this feature in Gtalk for Linux and Android version? Is this impossible for Google to add this feature?

Comment: @YumYumYum: Google Talk is not open source. Part of the core, [libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/), is open source, but the Talk app built around that core is not. Someone would probably have to extend libjingle and write a separate set of applications around it (or get Google to accept the core changes and hope they implement the necessary UI).